# How Symmetric is Diophantine Approximation using Fractions with Square Denominators?

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $S$ be an infinite set of positive integers. 
Let us say that a  "best S-approximation" to a real irrational $r$ is a rational number
$p/q$, with $p$ and $q$ integers and $q \in S$, such that for any integer $m\in S$ with $1 \le m<q$, and any integer $n$, it holds that $|p/q-r|<|n/m-r|$.

In the case that $S$ is the positive integers, it is well known that for any  $r$ there are infinitely many best $S$-approximations $p/q$ which are less than $r$ and infinitely many that are greater than $r$. This is proved for example in Khintchin's book "Continued Fractions."

What if $S$ is the set of squares of integers? Is it known that for every irrational $r$ there are infinitely many best $S$-approximations less than $r$ and infinitely many greater than $r$?

Experimentation with numerous commonplace irrationals gives the impression that the ratio of the number of under-estimates to the number of over-estimates tends to 1. Could this be true for every irrational $r$? Is this known?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that a natural version of the problem is finding how good are rational approximations of the form $p/q^k$ to a given irrational number $\theta$. This classical problem goes back to H. Heilbronn [*Quart. J. Math.* (Oxford) **19** (1948) 249--256] and I. Danicic [*Mathematika* **5** (1958) 30--37] and the best known results are due to C. Hooley [[in: *Analytic number theory*, Vol. 2 (Allerton Park, IL, 1995) 471–-486,
Progr. Math. **139** Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1996]](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/wadim/MO/Hooley-ANT1996.pdf) and G. Harman [[*Glasgow Math. J.* **38** (1996) 299–308]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0017089500031724). They show that there are infinitely many coprime pairs $p,q$ with the property
$$
\left|\theta-\frac p{q^k}\right|<\frac1{q^{k+\rho_k-\varepsilon}}
$$
where $\rho_2=\frac25$ and $\rho_k=1/(3\cdot 2^{k-2}-1)$ if $k\geq 3$.

Comment: @Wadim: Thank you for the references. Maybe my question is going to have to wait on a better understanding of how good rational approximations of the form $p/q^k$ can be.... But the numerical experiments I performed show such regular alternations between under and over-estimates that I hoped for a simple explanation. A real number all of whose best approximations of the form $p/q^2$ were overestimates would strike me as a very strange beast!

Comment: There is much more in the papers of Hooley and Hartman (for example, they discuss the question of choosing $q$ in the interval $1\le q\le N$). I believe that there is also a discussion (maybe, in Hooley's previous paper) on the expected $\rho_2$.

Comment: And a possible choice for your beast would be the Liouville example $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n!}$...

Comment: @Wadim: Why??!!

Comment: Aren't all best approximations of the form $\sum_{n=2}^N2^{-n!}=p/q^2$?

Comment: These can't be all of the best approximations, because they are all less than the Liouville number.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think when you say "any real" you mean "any real irrational." Second, you can find a real irrational such that all the even convergents, and none of the odd convergents, have square denominator. I think such an irrational would have infinitely many best $S$-approximations below but none above.

EDIT: Glyn Harman wrote a series of 4 papers, Metric Diophantine approximation with two restricted variables, which may have some relevance here.

Comment: Why should best S-approximations be convergents?

Comment: Gerry, I think you are failing to distinguish between best approximations of the "first and second kinds", as described in Khintchine's book, page 24. As Gjergji mentioned, best approximations in the sense of my question needn't be convergents!

As for restricting the question to irrationals, I'm not sure that's necessary, but it will avoid trivialities. I'll edit.

Comment: Best approximations needn't be convergents, but convergents are best approximations. My construction gives convergents which have square denominators and are underestimates. I'm suggesting this leaves no room for any best approximations which have square denominators and are overestimates. I acknowledge that there is some hand-waving here and many details to work out. 

Comment: More hand-waving; denominators of best approximations to a given real irrational are sparse. You wouldn't expect one to have a lot with square denominator - I bet almost all irrationals have only finitely many best approximations with square denominator. And if you construct one, as you can, with every other convergent having square denominator, then it's hugely unlikely to have many best approximations on the other side with square denominator. 

Comment: @Gerry:  Best $S$-approximations in the sense of the question are very different from best approximations with square denominators. I just don't see how best approximations can be used to control best $S$-approximations  -- I wish you could tell me! Incidentally, experimentation with various common irrationals (square roots of 2,3,5 etc) suggests that best $S$-approximations are about evenly divided between "bigger" and "smaller." Maybe there is a theorem to this effect, that holds for all irrationals? That's my guess.

Comment: Consider an irrational x which has among its convergents the rationals 29/64, 34/75, and 131/289 (yes, there are such). Will it have an approximation $p/q$ with $64<q<289$, $q$ a square, and $0<p/q-x<x-29/64$? It's hard to find approximations better that 29/64 with denominator less than 289, and on top of that you want it to be an overestimate, and with a square denominator. That's asking a lot!

Comment: @Gerry - OK, Let's take $r=131/289+00000001$. (Replace 00000001 with a small irrational if you like.) The convergents of $r$ are: $0/1, 1/2, 4/9, 5/11, 29/64, 34/75, 131/289, 156841/346008,\ldots$. The best $S$-approximations are $0/1, 2/4, 4/9, 22/49, 29/64, 102/225, 131/289,...$. Notice the little devil $102/225$!! It holds that `$102/225-r<r-29/64$`!

Comment: I didn't realize you were allowing fractions like 102/225 which are not in lowest terms. I still expect such things are exceptional, but clearly I am very far from being able to prove anything. 

Comment: @Gerry -- Actually, the inequality in the statement of my problem rules out fractions not in lowest terms, so the computation of offered in my previous comment is not a counter example to your intuition. Thanks for the reference -- I'll have a look.